# Clear already printed values using perl

Tags: perl

I need to clear the printed values in perl console window. For an example,
Note: I am developing this in Windows OS.

```
use strict;

my $mode;

Initialize();

sub Initialize{
    print "Enter 1 or 2";
    $mode=<STDIN>;
    chomp($mode); 
    check_mode($mode);
}

sub check_mode{
    if(($mode!=1) and ($mode!=2)){
        print "invalid selection";
        Initialize();
    }
    else{
        print "valid selection";
        sleep 5;
   }
}
```

While entering wrong selection, I have called the Initialize function, it is printing again. But, what I want is while calling the function it should delete already printed value in the console window and it should print again. Is it possible?

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: it may be intentional for testing, but do you realize the else-block in `sub check_mode` will never be reached? your `or` should be an `and`.

Comment: @ardnew good catch probably it should be `and` instead of `or`

Comment: yes... I have made mistake in it.. thanks for your info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for specific to window os and linux os

```
system($^O =~ /win/i ? 'cls' : 'clear');
```

Comment: Your regex will match `cygwin`, which would prefer to use `clear`.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use the backspace character code "\b" to erase characters on the current line, that has limitations since when the user hits enter it will print a linefeed and your backspace characters won't carry back up to erase the previous line.

See [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Console-0.09/Console.pm) which should allow you to print your prompt at a fixed location and then later overwrite the wrong selection or you can get input a single character at a time using the InputChar method and suppress the newline...